# Unity CollisionEnter2D being called multiple times every collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So I'm currently working on a unity boss fight game where lasers are meant to fire from above on a certain time interval (let's say like 10 seconds) after the player shoots the boss for the first time. What happens is when the boss is hit multiple times, it spawns multiple different laser projectiles. I'm using InvokeRepeating to do this, which I don't think is the most efficient way, so if anyone has any ideas on this, help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code (it's probably messy I'm pretty new to game development)

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class startboss : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool fight = false;

    public Sprite awake;

    public bool player_dead = false;

    public float spawntime = 10f;
    public float spawndelay = 10f;
    public bool spawn = false;



    // Start is called before the first frame update

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Bullet")
        {
           
            spawn = true;
            fight = true;
            if (fight == true)
            {
                gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = awake;
                if (spawn == true)
                {
                    InvokeRepeating("Shoot", spawntime, spawndelay);
                }
            }
        }
    }

                public GameObject laserprefab;
    public Transform laserpoint;
    public Transform laserpoint2;
    public float seconds = 10;
    public Rigidbody2D rblaser;

    // Start is called before the first frame update

    // Update is called once per frame

    // Start is called before the first frame update

    void Shoot()
    {
        Instantiate(laserprefab, laserpoint.position, laserpoint.rotation);
        Instantiate(laserprefab, laserpoint2.position, laserpoint2.rotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this doesn't follow formula for regular posts on here, this is my first one so sorry If I'm not under some etiquette.

Comment: I know you are "new" but setting a ```bool``` variable to ```true``` and then checking ```if(x == true){...}``` right after is kind of unnecessary :-D its not gonna miraculously change state from one line to the next ;)

Comment: What is exactly your issue? What is happening vs what you expect? Can you elaborate more or is your question about ```InvokeRepeating``` and performance?

Comment: @Tomek Thanks for helping out. Basically the laser projectiles are meant to fire every 10 seconds, but when the actual enemy is shot, it duplicates the lasers, for example when I shoot the boss, it spawns 1 laser per blaster every 10 seconds, but If I shoot the boss 3 more times, It spawns 3 lasers per 1 blaster every 10 seconds. Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: That sounds to me that you re-subscribe the event handler on each collision from your blaster? You just need to subscribe the EventHandler ```OnCollisionEnter2D``` eg when you load/initialize the scene/boss etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating a new InvokeRepeating("Shoot", spawntime, spawndelay); every time you shoot the boss so it will start another instance of Shoot repeating. So if you shoot the boss 3 times you will have 3 repeating Shoots going on.

You could move the shooting outside of the collision and use a timer to count down instead of InvokeRepeating to have more control. If you need you can set the timer to 0 or stop / start the timer on collision.

```
    //Declair timer and time
    float fireTimer = 0.0f;
    float fireTime = spawnTime;

    void Update(){ 
         
         //Add time to the timer.
         fireTimer += Time.deltaTime;
         
         //If timer = time then fire and reset the timer.
         if(fireTimer == fireTime){
              Shoot();
              fireTimer = 0.0f;
         }
    }
```